# JavaScript - Need help with string manipulation

Tags: javascript

say you have:

```
var foo = "donut [$25]"
```

What would you need to do in order to delete everything between and including the `[ ]`.

so you get: `foo = "donut"` after the code is run.

So far I have tried most of the solutions below, but they all either do nothing or crash.
Maybe it's something with my code, please see below:

```
 $('select').change(function () { OnSuccess(mydata); });


    function OnSuccess(data) {

        var total = 0;

        $('select').each(function () {


            var sov = parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')) || 0; //Selected option value

            var sop; //Selected Option Price


            for (i = 0; i <= data.length; i++) {


                if (data[i].partid == sov) {

                    sop = data[i].price;
                    total += sop;
                    $('#totalprice').html(total);
                    break;
                }


            };








            //debugger;
            $(this).find('option').each(function () {

                // $(this).append('<span></span>');

                var uov = parseInt($(this).attr('value')) || 0; //Unselected option value

                var uop; //Unselected Option Price


                for (d = 0; d <= data.length; d++) {


                    if (data[d].partid == uov) {

                        uop = data[d].price;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                //debugger;
                var newtext = uop - sop;
                //{ newtext = "" };
                //if (newtext = 0) { newtext.toString; newtext = ""; };


                //debugger;
                var xtext = $(this).text().toString();

                //if (xtext.match(/\[.*\]/) != null) {
                    xtext.replace(/\s*\[[\s\S]*?\]\s*/g, '').trim();

                //}

                //                var temp = xtext.split('[')[0];
                //                var temp2 = xtext.split(']')[1];

                //                resultx = temp + temp2;

                if (newtext != 0) {


                    //xtext.replace(/[.*?]/, "");

                    $(this).attr("text", xtext + " " + "[" + "$" + newtext + "]");
                };





            });







        });


    };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a regular expression, as Jon Martin pointed out:

var yum = "donut[$25]";
  yum.replace(/[.*?]/, ""); // returns "donut"

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
var temp = foo.split('[')[0];
var temp2 = foo.split(']')[1];

foo = temp + temp2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions (the `RegExp()` object) to match strings.

```
var foo = "donut[$25]";
foo.match(/\[.*\]/);
```

The above will return an array of every item in [square brackets], in this case `["[$25]"]`.

To just get one result as a string, specify the first index like so:

```
foo.match(/\[.*\]/)[0];
```

The above will return `"[$25]"`

Edit: You know what? I completely misread which bit of the string you're after. This is what you're after:

```
var foo = "donut[$25]";
foo.match(/\w*/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about simply;

```
var yum = "donut[$25]";
print( yum.substr(0, yum.indexOf("[")) );

>>donut
```

Comment: This won't work for strings that have characters after the ']'.

Comment: It will work for `donut[$34]weqweqwe` as it truncates at the 1st `[` which seems reasonable for what appears to be structured data

Comment: He only wanted to delete everything between [..] inclusively. Your method will delete everything after the ].

Comment: var xtext = $(this).text().toString();
                xtext.substr(0, xtext.indexOf("[")); - Does not seem to be doing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

var begin = foo.search("[");
var end   = foo.search("]");
var result = foo.substr(0, begin) + foo.substr(end+1); //Combine anything before [ and after ]

Should be ok right?

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves unspecified the treatment of the spaces before the [ character, anything after the ], will your string ever contain a linefeed character, multiple occurrences of [..], leading or trailing spaces.

The following will replace all occurrences of '*spaces* [ ... ] *spaces*' with a single space, then it trims the result to remove any leading/trailing spaces.

```
   v.replace (/\s*\[[\s\S]*?\]\s*/g, ' ').trim ();
```